# RPi4 w/ Centos and RPI.GPIO: can't add edge detection

Tags: python-3.x, centos7, gpio

I am running CentOS7 with kernel 5.4.206-v8.1.el7 on a RPi4 and I am trying to setup edge detection on GPIO with RPi.GPIO-0.7.1-py3.9 (*)

I am getting the following error whatever the pin I try to configure:

`RPi.GPIO.add_event_detect(self.pin, RPi.GPIO.BOTH, self._on_event) RuntimeError: Failed to add edge detection`

I also get it when I run in sudo. I previously tuned the permissions to get:

`[blabla@hostname]$  ls -l /dev/gpiomem  crw-rw----. 1 root gpio 246, 0 Jan  1  1970 /dev/gpiomem`

so that GPIO in output mode (to blink a LED for instance) works fine.

Running my basic RPi.GPIO-based edge detection code (*) with strace I noticed a few suspicious lines:

`faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/class/gpio/gpio6", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/class/gpio/export", O_WRONLY) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)`

1. I thought RPi.GPIO was now based on GPIO character and not sysfs anymore? Although I am far from being an expert so I may be wrong / confused
2. I looked a bit into /sys/class/gpio on my RPi:

`[blabla@hostname]$ ls /sys/class/gpio/ export  gpiochip446  gpiochip454  unexport`

It seems to me that attempting to create /sys/class/gpio/gpio6 makes no sense here, one should read the base of the controller and do base+6 ? Wouldn't that explain the Permission denied?

3. I tried to run the event.c example of the bcm2835 library and this works fine, ie button pressed are detected correctly. For technical reasons I would like to use RPi.GPIO.

Sorry again I am far from being an expert so maybe just confused myself, any help to unblock the situation would be great!

Thanks a lot
Best wishes

(*)

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

X=6

# Set pin X in GPIO mode
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(X, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

# Define a callback function to detect edge events
def my_callback(channel):
    print(f"Edge event detected on pin {X}")

# Set the callback function
GPIO.add_event_detect(X, GPIO.RISING, callback=my_callback)

# Main loop
try:
    while True:
        pass

# Exit gracefully
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: I would recommend to switch either to `gpio-keys` module and consume it as an input device (like keyboard, or attach a handler to that interrupt using a daemon). Or switch your code to use `libgpiod` (have you tried with `gpiomon` tool? Does it work?).

Comment: as far as I know this module is available only from Centos8 (https://rhel.pkgs.org/8/epel-x86_64/libgpiod-1.4.3-1.el8.x86_64.rpm.html)

I will try to compile it by hand

Comment: So I downloaded libgpiod 1.4.5 and it works. As I want to use python3.9 I installed gpiod from pip and migrated my low-level code to use gpiod rather than RPi.GPIO and it works.